# Navbar Collapsable Burger Menu not working with Jquery 3.5

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

As the title says when using Bootstrap 4.4.1 and JQuery 3.5.0 for some objects there occurs the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
```

The Problem can be fixed by reverting to JQuery https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle? I think you should file a bug report.

Comment: Have you tried to use jQuery Migrate to find out? I've got a similar problem and that helped me a lot.